# CKEditor: Bold, Italic, Underline can only be applied to already written text on Chrome

Tags: ckeditor, grails-plugin

I am using ckeditor 0.4 v plugin for my grails application (Grails 1.3.7).

In Chrome and Safari browser Bold, Italic and Underline button only works for already written text (only selected text), it doesn't work for the text you are about to write.

It works fine on FireFox and IE. I can click on the Bold button and type bold text and also select the already written text and click on bold will make it bold.

This issue has been resolved in latest version but as I cant upgrade the version of ckeditor plugin I want the patch for this issue for ckeditor 0.4v

you can also see @
http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/5982

Comment: 1. you have not described the issue precisely, 2. it is very unlikely that someone will understand what you are writing about, 3. it is even more unlikely that someone will be able to find a patch for CKEditor 3.2.1 which is included in CKEditor Grails plugin v0.4.

Comment: Added description for the issue. hope this information will help you to understand the issue.And related to adding the patch,I found some patch and added in the plugin but wont work because there are lot of changes 0.4v to 3.6v. so if you can help me in finding any other solution for this issue then that will be great!!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for you - update CKEditor Grails plugin. That patch is huge and landed in the main code line looong after the CKEditor 3.2.1 (to be precise - in CKEditor 3.5.3) which is used in the **very old** CKEditor Grails plugin 0.4.

BTW. do not confuse CKEditor 4.0 with CKEditor Grails plugin 0.4 - these are completely separate projects.

Comment: I got the patch for this issue on http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/1272   made some changes and applied it.And It works!!! :)